# What does the line number refer to in hive error logs?

Tags: hive, error-log

I tried running this query:

```
SET hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias=true;
SELECT device, COUNT (DISTINCT from_user) AS users_sharing
FROM dileep.oct_activation_device_info
GROUP BY  1 order by 2 desc limit 10
```

It threw an error with the following error message:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: 
Line 1:31 Invalid table alias or column reference 'from_user': (possible column names are: device, users_sharing)
```

What does the `1:31` in the log mean in reference to the above query?

PS: The question is about the log meaning specifically. The query is only for example.

Comment: the `from_user` after `DISTINCT` - it's line 1 column 31.

Comment: @AlexL.How does that refer to line 1:31 in the logs?

Comment: line 1: `SELECT device, COUNT (DISTINCT from_user) AS users_sharing` 31'st char: `from_user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SET hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias=true;` is irrelevant since it's a different command - the error refers to the `SELECT` command.

Line 1 is the first line (it's 1 based): `SELECT device, COUNT (DISTINCT from_user) AS users_sharing`

31 is the location in the line: `from_user`. It seems that the location is zero based.

Comment: Got it. The first query has caused my confusion as I was counting from there. Now it seems like a silly question :)

Comment: I don't think it is - I also got confused a couple of times since you usually run several commands